# unable to see the databases when using the hive as a metastore

Tags: hadoop, hive, derby, apache-hive, metastore

In order to access the hive through the Apache Drill, I have started the metastore as a service.

In order to use it as a metastore in the hive-site.xml, I have set the hive.metastore.uris parameter to thrift://localhost:9083.

After the metastore service is created, I am trying to view the databases.It shows only two databases instead of 4 which are created before starting the hive as a service.

Also few tables which are created before are not shown.

When i browsed through the folder /hive/user/warehouse/, I could see all the tables and all the databases.

When i stop the metastore as a service and check it shows all the 4 databases.I am not sure what is going behind.

Can anyone please help me, if you face the same and what needs to be done?

I am using Apache Derby as a backend database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different versions of Hive are installed in the same linux machine.Hence I faced that issue.Have removed the version which I am not using and then the issue resolved.It's my mistake.

Comment: To make sure the question does not remain open, I would recomend you to accept your own answer.

Comment: Having multiple versions of Hive is not the issue. Looks like your HiveMetastore is started with wrong derby path.